# Least squares - why multiply both sides by the transpose?

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-algebra

The formula:

$A^T(b - Ax) = 0\\
A^Tb = A^TAx\\
x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$

What is the reason for multiplying both sides by the transpose of A?

Comment: Are you referring to the first equation? That is the least squares optimality condition.

Comment: Yes, as Mark said you need to have complete derivation of the normal equation to get solution for beta - vector.

Comment: I found the duplicates by [searching](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=least%20squares%20formula%20matrix); I know there are many more.